# Showing undefined in excel label

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase-realtime-database

**Problem**

It is showing on exported excel file `undefine`. But there is no empty array index for it.

**Code**

```
const joinDate = new Date(obj.date);
let snap = [
    obj.name,
    obj.surename,
    obj.email,
    obj.nip,
    obj.phone,
    obj.adress + " " + obj.home + " " + (obj.local=="brak" ? "" : obj.local),
    obj.city,
    obj.zip,
    obj.spentPoint,
    '',
    ''
];
orders.push(new Promise((resolve) => {
    let userNip = i;
    let ordersRef = firebase.database().ref('/orders/' + userNip);

    ordersRef.once("value", (snapshot) => {
        let ord = snapshot.val();
        let i = 0;

        for(let u in ord) {
            let o = ord[u];
            let newDate = new Date(o.date);
            let formatttedDate = String(newDate.getDate()) + "/" + String(newDate.getMonth()+1) + "/" + String(newDate.getFullYear());
            snap[10+i] = formatttedDate;
            for(let x in o.items) {
                snap[9+i] += String(o.items[x].title) + "[ Punktów: " + o.items[x].summary + " ]";
            }
            i = i + 2;
        }
        resolve();
    })
}));
data.push(snap);
```

In excel look like:

> name surename ..... 1st product name, 1st product date, undefined2nd product name, 2nd product date.

I do not know from where it get undefined.

There is no less data in array that can show undefine.

[image: Screen from excel:]

I draw red line on problem. And it is still going on 3,4,5 item etc...

What is a problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`snap[9+i]` is giving you `undefined`. What's the 9 for? The 10?

If you're targetting a specific item in `snap`, then always access it at a static index like `snap[1]` or `snap[9]` or `snap[10]`.

It's breaking because you're adding 9 + 1 and looking for the 11th+ item in an array that doesn't have 11 items.

Edit:

If you have the maintain the format, which isn't a great way to display data but might be needed for some external process, try something like:

```
const joinDate = new Date(obj.date);
let snap = [
  obj.name,
  obj.surename,
  obj.email,
  obj.nip,
  obj.phone,
  obj.adress + " " + obj.home + " " + (obj.local=="brak" ? "" : obj.local),
  obj.city,
  obj.zip,
  obj.spentPoint,
];

  orders.push(new Promise((resolve) => {
  let userNip = i;
  let ordersRef = firebase.database().ref('/orders/' + userNip);

  ordersRef.once("value", snapshot=>{
    let ord = snapshot.val();

    for(let u in ord){
      let o = ord[u];
      let newDate = new Date(o.date);
      let formatttedDate = String(newDate.getDate()) + "/" + String(newDate.getMonth()+1) + "/" + String(newDate.getFullYear());

      snap.push(formatttedDate);
      for(let x in o.items){
        snap.push(String(o.items[x].title) + "[ Punktów: " + o.items[x].summary + " ]");
      }

    }
    resolve();
  })
}))
data.push(snap);
```

Comment: The index in snap i making columuns in excel. That the item will be on 9, 11, 13, 15 etc. How i can make it in other way if this is bad?

Comment: What is the data supposed to look like? 1 line per customer with customer information columns, then 1 column for the date, and 1 column with a summary of all the items?

Comment: Yea, 1 line per customer with few columns with data (phone, zip-code etc), and after this all items with data seperated for each columns

Comment: Can you split it into 1 line per item? Would make reporting and parsing in Excel a lot easier, or is it a requirement that you can only have 1 line per order with all line items in the same line but different columns?

Comment: It is requirement from client : /

Comment: Ah ok - then to just keep adding elements to the array, use `.push()`.

Comment: See edited answer - if you're just saying "per item, add on a formatted date column and then a a column for the items", you can just do 2 pushes. Saying `array[nonexistent index]` usually won't work because those elements don't exist yet, but if you `push` a new value, it should be added to the end of your array